# Getting BXNUI0005E error while trying to create a new app

Tags: ibm-cloud

I am trying to create a sample app using the Liberty Java API but I am getting following error:

> BXNUI0005E: The 'SampleJavaApp' application could not be added. See
>   the Troubleshooting topics in the IBM Bluemix Documentation to check
>   service status, review troubleshooting information, or for information
>   about getting help.

My dashboard is showing that more than 1GB of space is available in my workspace. It seems to be an issue at Bluemix end. Please help in resolving it.

Thanks & Regards,
Prerna

Answer (score 0):

Usually this problem occurs when an application with the same name already exists. *SampleJavaApp* is quite generic. Try to choose a unique name.

Comment: Thanks. It worked with different name. The error message should be clear about the problem.